# how to separate services from component

Tags: reactjs

I created my service file like this :

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const getAll = () => {
    const apiData = axios
        .get('https://localhost:44390/api/DCandidate')
    return apiData
}
```

and call it in App function like this:

```
import * as candidate from './services/dCandidateService'

function App() {

  const myData = candidate.getAll()
  console.log(myData)

  return (
    <>
      Axios Testing
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

after calling getAll() it returns response like this: [image]

is it possible to return only data array?
please help.

Comment: It will have to be a Promise, but you can change what value that Promise wraps: `return apiData.then(result => resut.data)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can return the data array itself. You need to make the function async and wait for the result. Once the result is there, return it's data part.

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const getAll = async () => {
    const apiData = (await axios.get('https://localhost:44390/api/DCandidate')).data
    return apiData
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It returns a Promise object. Under value node i got my data. actually i want to print only the data array